# How to test AJAX functionality in Rails 3?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

In a Rails 3 application, I have a div that adds more data when the user scrolls down to the bottom via AJAX, similar to Twitter. How would you write a test for this? Currently I am using the built-in test functionality, but is there a better way?

Also, the first version I wrote worked fine in Chrome, but not on IE7. Is it possible to write a test that would check to see if it works in a given browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to test server-side, or client-side?

Comment: To test the whole chain, check [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara). To test only client-side, [check this one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine).

Comment: This [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510657) might be useful too.

Comment: I would just suggest, although the Railscast uses RSpec, to use cucumber (http://cukes.info/) instead. Loads better for acceptance testing in my opinion.

Comment: Do you have a resource you recommend for getting started with cucumber?

Comment: Well http://www.cukes.info has some examples, and you can find many online. I didn't really use a resource myself, because someone else taught me it, but it's not hard to get yourself started with it. I've seen some tutorials online too, but unfortunately I didn't pay enough attention to be able to confidentially recommend you one.

Comment: There are some Railscasts about cucumber as well